# Install Encrypted Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Proxmox

Tags: server, 20.04, encryption, lvm, cryptsetup

i am trying to install an encrypted Ubuntu 20.04 Server on Proxmox.
I used the LVM option aswell as the encryption option of the installer.

**lsblk** gives me:

```
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                         7:0    0 29.9M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/8542
loop1                         7:1    0   55M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1880
loop2                         7:2    0 71.3M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/16099
loop3                         7:3    0 59.6M  1 loop  /snap/powershell/137
sda                           8:0    0 18.6T  0 disk
├─sda1                        8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                        8:2    0    1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                        8:3    0 18.6T  0 part
└─dm_crypt-1              253:0    0 18.6T  0 crypt
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:1    0  200G  0 lvm   /
sr0                          11:0    1  914M  0 rom
sr1                          11:1    1  1.6G  0 rom
sr2                          11:2    1 1024M  0 rom
```

showing my 18.6T crypt.

But in **df -h** there is no filesystem that large.

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                97G     0   97G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               20G  1.2M   20G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   11G  176G   6% /
tmpfs                               95G     0   95G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               95G     0   95G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  103M  806M  12% /boot
/dev/loop0                          30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop1                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop2                          72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16099
/dev/loop3                          60M   60M     0 100% /snap/powershell/137
tmpfs                               19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/1000
```

So how can i create a logical volume so i can use the space on the crypt?

Here is my **/etc/fstab**:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-IdCQcgtk7FSsjYlhEUv98iCG3xH3YFLmNwNK2cUqH2mvo1OujMfgjPB15wYlSUNM / ext4>
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f20bf465-8640-45d2-a6ab-4d82ed5dbaef /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

and here is the **/etc/crypttab**:

```
dm_crypt-1 UUID=55cc21ee-a756-40fa-a677-69c84d023b8d none luks
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after surfing for two days, i found the solution is pretty easy after all:

**1) Extend your logical volume:**

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

**2) Resize the Filesystem:**

```
resize2fs -p  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Done.

I hope it will help others.